# Image shows up twice in internet explorer 9 while it shows it perfectly in firefox or chrome

Tags: html, css

Like the title says, in IE an image shows up twice but it shows up perfectly in other browsers.. Now the weird thing is it shows up wrong on 2 of my 5 pages. While the code is the same for all.

The thing is the html code for both navigation parts are exactly the same and they get the image from the same css file..

Could anyone check what could be wrong?

CSS:

```
a img
{
border:none;
}

body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #7f7e7e;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #ffffff
background-image: url(images/#####.pg);
background-repeat: repeat-x

}

#container {
width: 1200px;
margin: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
width: 1200px;
height: 130px;
}



#logo {
background-image: url(../images/logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 425px;
height: 87px;
margin-top: 28px;
margin-left: 128px;
float: left;
}

#logo_des {
background-image: url(../images/logo2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 311px;
height: 57px;
float: right;
margin-top: 57px;
margin-right: 37px;
}




.nav_menu li { 
list-style: none;
display: inline;
margin-left: 159px;
line-height: 40px;


}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> <title> x</title>

    <link href = "styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>

<body>
<a name="top">
<div id="container"> <!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
<div id="header"> <!--BEGIN HEADER -->
<div id="logo"><!-- BEGIN LOGO -->
</div><!-- END LOGO -->     

<div id="logo_des"> <!-- BEGIN LOGO DESCRIPTION -->
</div> <!--END LOGO DESCRIPTION -->

</div> <!--END HEADER-->

<div id="navigation_line"> <!-- BEGIN NAVIGATION_LINE -->
<div id="menu"> <!--BEGIN MENU-->

<ul class="nav_menu">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about_x.html">About x</a></li>
<li><a href="our_services.html">Our Services</a></li>
<li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="partners.html">Partners</a></li>
</ul>   
</div> <!-- END NAVIGATION_LINE -->
</div> <!--END MENU--> `
```

Answer (score 1):

Stupid of me, I forgot to put it through the validator. Fixed some mistakes and its done now.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close some of your open tags :)